# How to find if a set of objects share one property, which can be either of two properties?

Tags: python

I'm trying to check whether a list of objects have one of two properties identical between them.

As in:

```py
class Test():
  def __init__(self, prop1, prop2):
    self.prop1 = prop1
    self.prop2 = prop2

print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(1, 2), Test(1, 3)]))
print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(2, 1), Test(3, 1)]))
print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(2, 1), Test(1, 2)]))
```

Would result in an output of:

```py
(True, "prop1")
(True, "prop2")
(False, None)
```

Because:

- for all three objects `prop1 == 1`.
- for all three objects `prop2 == 1`.
- for all three objects there is no attribute with the same value.

How can this be done? What should be the `Check` function?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: What is `Check`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a set out of the properties and see whether its size is one when you've finished:

```
def Check(values):
    prop1 = {v.prop1 for v in values}
    prop2 = {v.prop2 for v in values}
    if len(prop1) == 1:
        return True, 'prop1'
    elif len(prop2) == 1:
        return True, 'prop2'
    else:
        return False, None
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all objects are from the same class, you can iterate over the attributes, and check if they are identical through all objects:

```py
def Check(objects):
    for attr, value in vars(objects[0]).items():
        if all(getattr(obj, attr) == value for obj in objects[1:]):
            return (True, attr)

    return (False, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__dict__` method to get the attributes then apply set `intersection` to get the match

```py
from functools import reduce

def Check(l):
    match = reduce(lambda x,y: set(x).intersection(y), [i.__dict__.items() for i in l]) 
    return (True, match) if len(match)>0 else (False, None)


class Test():
    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2

print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(1, 2), Test(1, 3)]))
print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(2, 1), Test(3, 1)]))
print(Check([Test(1, 1), Test(2, 1), Test(1, 2)]))

# (True, {('prop1', 1)})
# (True, {('prop2', 1)})
# (False, None)
```